# Best solution for drag/drop category/subcategory? Tried jQuery UI sortable, now stuck

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, categories

I have a very crude category list right now, but I'm wanting it to make it look and behave more like WordPress admin does it, where you can drag a category into another category.

[image: categories]

Code looks like this:

```
<ul class="categories">
    <li>Real Estate</li>
    <li>Home Improvements</li>
    <ul class="categories">
        <li>Interior</li>
        <li>Exterior</li>
        <ul class="categories">
            <li>Exterior Subcat</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I tried jQuery UI's sortable, and told it to sort `<li>`'s only, but the list items wouldn't drag outside of their parent `<ul>` list into another `<ul>` list.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Will this help? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [Sortable + nested lists with jQuery UI 1.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308672/sortable-nested-lists-with-jquery-ui-1-8-2)

And plugin: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/