# jQuery UI sortable connect sortable rows with unsortable rows

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been working on a little page sorting system for a cms system. Currently I'm displaying my data (all pages) in a table which I've made sortable thanks to jQuery UI. The only problem is that no child page rows are assigned to any parent row like a unsorted list inside a list object etc. I've made a little example to show you guys what I mean.

http://www.lautenbagreclame.nl/stackover_example.jpg

```
$('table#pages-overview tbody').sortable({

    handle : 'i.icon-resize-vertical',
    opacity : 0.3,
    placeholder : 'drag-drop-table-row',
    axis : 'y',
    helper: fixHelper,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    cursor: 'n-resize',
    zIndex: 9999,
    start: function(event, ui) {

        elementObjPagesOverview.children('tr').each(function() {
            if($(this).data('group') != ui.helper.data('group')) {
                // row isnt in the same group... so not allowed to connect !
            } else {
                // row is in the same group... so allowed to connect !
            }
        });

    }

});
```

The whole table is dynamicly build. Hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be the solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308672/sortable-nested-lists-with-jquery-ui-1-8-2

Regards

Comment: I've been looking into it, but couldnt find the solution you are prefering to. Those examples work with <ul>'s and <li>'s where mine works with table rows. Could you be more specific maybe?