# JQuery: Drag, drop, sort nested list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, nested-lists, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to use draggable, droppable, & sortable to create nested lists. I'm looking to drag(clone) items from preset lists to a container with the ability to create nested lists. The diagram below shows a simple example.
[image]

Below is my code (note this is just snippet of my project and might reference things not in the Code Snippet) which allows me to drag the items to the container and sort on them.
But I can't nest them to create sublists. If I create a predefined list in the container, I can sort/nest them. It's like drag n drop is the issue.
Looking over the jQuery docs and similar questions here on SO its not clear to me how to do it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
$( "#draggable-elements li" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",           
  helper: "clone"
});
$( ".logic-container ul" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "highlight",            
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  greedy: true,
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).hide();
    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
  }
});

$(".logic-container ul").sortable({
  connectWith: ".logic-container ul",
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});
```

```css
.dropped {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed #999;     
  width: 90%;  
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="draggable-elements">
  <li class="elements">Item 1<ul></ul></li>
  <li class="elements">Item 2<ul></ul></li>
  <li class="elements">Item 3<ul></ul></li>
</ul>

<div class="logic-container">
  <ul class="dropped">            
  </ul>          
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x16texhg/**

## Update

I got the nesting to work, but I cannot nest items within dragged items that was dragged into the container. Dragging a new Item into the container can be nested but any existing or new items cannot be nested. I think its a class issue, but cant seem to figure it out. Updated fiddle:

```js
$("#example1 li").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  connectToSortable: "#example5 ul"
});

$("#example5 ul").sortable({
  connectWith: "#example5 ul",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  toleranceElement: "ul"
});
```

```css
ul {min-height:20px; background:red; clear:both;}
li {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:10px; background:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="example1">
  <li><div>New Item</div><ul></ul></li>    
</ul>

<div id="example5"> 
  <ul>        
    <li ><div>Item 2</div><ul></ul>
      <ul> 
        <li ><div>Item 1 1</div><ul></ul></li> 
        <li ><div>Item 1 2</div><ul></ul></li> 
        <li ><div>Item 1 3</div><ul></ul></li> 
      </ul> 
    </li>         
  </ul> 
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/carbongixxer/x16texhg/2/**

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308672/sortable-nested-lists-with-jquery-ui-1-8-2

Comment: and this one 

https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: @knizer Thanks for the pointing me to the plugin, but I think I should be able to achieve this without it.